# How to unit test azure function using Xunit and Moq

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, moq, xunit.net

I am very new to unit tests and recently started learning it from various online resources.
But still it confuses me when I need to implement it in my code.

For the given image which I have attached here, could anyone of you suggest me how should I start or where to start?

This is Azure function which I will be creating unit test for, framework/library I would prefer is Xunit and moq.

[image: AzureFunctionUnitTest]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code, copy the original text to the question (and use the code format tool)

Comment: When writing tests, ask yourself "What functionality of the code am I validating?" In the code you provided, there isn't a lot testing to be done. "Does this do the right thing when `inventoryRequest` is/is not `null`?" is about all you can really test for. So you mock your `inventoryService` and `logger` instances, and test that the mocks are being called under the correct circumstances. Ideally. you would also be testing the logic contained in the `ProcessRequest` method.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for your comment!  The processRequest is having strings , numbers , and Lists so I guess I will have to write dummy data for it , right ?

Comment: @Narru007 Yes. You shape the input so that it will trigger the scenarios you are trying to test.

Comment: But... if you must share a picture use something like the Snipping Tool for goodness sake, lol! No need to use you're phone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, a good place to start when unit testing is looking at your code and identifying the different "paths" it can take and what the result of that path will be.

```
if (inventoryRequest != null)
{
    // path 1
    await _inventoryService.ProcessRequest(inventoryRequest);
    _logger.LogInformation("HBSI Inventory Queue trigger function processed.");
}
else
{
    // path 2
    _logger.LogInformation("Unable to process HBSI Rate plan Queue.");
}
```

In your code, because of your `if` statement, there are 2 possible paths which will end in 2 different results = 2 unit tests.

Now you can start creating your unit tests but first you need to find out what you need to set up to be able to trigger your code.

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly IInventoryService _inventoryService;

public InventoryServiceBusFunction(ILogger logger, IInventoryService inventoryService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _inventoryService = inventoryService;
}
```

You have some dependencies being passed into your constructor with interfaces - great, this means we can mock them. We want to mock dependencies in unit tests because we want to control their behaviour for the tests. Also, mocking the dependencies negates any "real" behaviour the dependency might be performing i.e. database operations, API calls etc.

Using Moq we can mock the objects like so:

```
public class InventoryServiceBusFunctionTests
{
    private readonly Mock<ILogger> _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
    private readonly Mock<IInventoryService> _mockInventoryService = new Mock<IInventoryService>();
    
    ...
```

We will use these mocks later to make verifications on behaviour we expect to happen.

Next, we need to create an instance of the actual class we want to test.

```
// using a constructor in the test class will run this code before each test
public InventoryServiceBusFunctionTests()
{
    // pass the mocked objects to initialize class
    _inventoryServiceBusFunction = new InventoryServiceBusFunction(_mockLogger.Object, _mockInventoryService.Object);
}
```

Now that we have an instance of the `InventoryServiceBusFunction` class, we can use any of the public properties/methods in our tests.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GivenInventoryRequest_WhenFunctionRuns_ThenInventoryServiceProcessesRequest()
{
```

Now, remembering the paths from earlier, we can start to create the test cases. We can take the first path and create a `[Fact]` for it. You want to give your test case a meaningful name. I usually use the style of `Given_When_Then` to describe what is expected to happen.

Next, I usually add 3 comment sections to my test case:

```
// arrange

// act

// assert
```

This allows me to clearly see which parts of the test are doing what.

```
// act
await _inventoryServiceBusFunction.Run(inventoryRequest);
```

Next, I would fill in the `\\ act` section because this will tell me (via Intellisense) what I need to arrange. e.g. above, when hovering my mouse over the `Run` method, I can see that I need to pass an instance of `InventoryRequest`.

```
// arrange
var inventoryRequest = new InventoryRequest
{
    Name = "abc123",
    Quantity = 2,
    Tags = new List<string>
    {
        "foo"
    }
};
```

In the `\\ arrange` section, initialize an instance of the `InventoryRequest` class and set the properties. This can be any data as we aren't really interested in the data itself but more what happens when the code runs.

```
if (inventoryRequest != null)
{
    // path 1
    await _inventoryService.ProcessRequest(inventoryRequest);
    _logger.LogInformation("HBSI Inventory Queue trigger function processed.");
}
```

Lastly, the `\\ assert` section. Here, we want to make assertions on what we expect to happen given the set up of the test. So given the `InventoryRequest` is not null, we expect the `if` to evaluate to true and we expect the `_inventoryService.ProcessRequest(inventoryRequest)` method to be executed.

```
// assert
_mockInventoryService
    .Verify(x => x.ProcessRequest(It.Is<InventoryRequest>(ir => ir.Name == inventoryRequest.Name 
                                                                && ir.Quantity == inventoryRequest.Quantity 
                                                                && ir.Tags.Contains(inventoryRequest.Tags[0]))));
```

In Moq, we can use the `.Verify()` method on the mock object to assert that the  method was called. We can use the `It.Is<T>` syntax to make assertions on the data that is passed to the method.

Here is the full test case for path 1:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GivenInventoryRequest_WhenFunctionRuns_ThenInventoryServiceProcessesRequest()
{
    // arrange
    var inventoryRequest = new InventoryRequest
    {
        Name = "abc123",
        Quantity = 2,
        Tags = new List<string>
        {
            "foo"
        }
    };

    // act
    await _inventoryServiceBusFunction.Run(inventoryRequest);

    // assert
    _mockInventoryService
        .Verify(x => x.ProcessRequest(It.Is<InventoryRequest>(ir => ir.Name == inventoryRequest.Name 
                                                                    && ir.Quantity == inventoryRequest.Quantity 
                                                                    && ir.Tags.Contains(inventoryRequest.Tags[0]))));
}
```

Then for path 2, you are setting up the test so that the `else` condition is executed.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GivenInventoryRequestIsNull_WhenFunctionRuns_ThenInventoryServiceDoesNotProcessRequest()
{
    // arrange
    InventoryRequest inventoryRequest = null;

    // act
    await _inventoryServiceBusFunction.Run(inventoryRequest);

    // assert
    _mockInventoryService
        .Verify(x => x.ProcessRequest(It.IsAny<InventoryRequest>()), Times.Never);
}
```

Note - in the `\\ assert` here, I am asserting that the `await _inventoryService.ProcessRequest(inventoryRequest)` method is never called. This is because you want the test to fail in this scenario as the method should only be executed in the `if` condition. You may also choose to verify that the logger method is called with the correct message.

Comment: Great explanation !  Had to add private InventoryServiceBusFunction _inventoryServiceBusFunction; everything else was working fine. Also I have used Autofixture for creating dummy data for InventoryRequest because this class is having complex types so was tough to create manually. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: For Logger I have added these lines right after the _mockInventoryService assert,  _mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Info(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);  Is this correct or not?

Comment: @Narru007 that will work but you may want to be more specific with the assertion i.e. `_mockLogger.Verify(x => x.Info(It.Is<string>(s == "Unable to process HBSI Rate plan Queue.")), Times.Once)`

Comment: Is there a way I can get you a coffee or tea?. You cleared my doubts with such a great explanation.

Comment: @Narru007 no need - glad to have been able to help :)

Comment: I have one code with exception , how should I test it ? the code is                           
        public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error($"IBS inventory queue error., Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }    Edit : Is there anything to be tested or I can skip this one?

Comment: @Narru007 You may be able to use Moq to mock the `FunctionContext` and `FunctionExecutionDelegate` parameters. Then you could set up the `FunctionExecutionDelegate` mock to throw an exception and verify that your mock `_logger` was called.

Comment: I have one doubt Chris , in my earlier question you suggested to mock only dependencies and for InventoryRequest parameter you created dummy data ( though I used autofixture to create automatically ) , so going with the same approach I have created mock only for Ilogger . Do we mock parameters as well ? Sorry for being so dumb

Comment: this is what I did so far (not sure if it is correct or not)--   var fixture = new Fixture();
          #pragma warning disable CS8603 // Possible null reference return.
            fixture.Register<FunctionContext>(() => null);
          #pragma warning restore CS8603 // Possible null reference return.
            var context = fixture.Create<FunctionContext>();
            var next = fixture.Create<FunctionExecutionDelegate>();

            // act
            await _exceptionLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(context, next);

            _ee.Verify(x => x.Equals(next));

Comment: @Narru007 create a new question and post your full code. Send me the link and I'll try and help.

Comment: I have posted the full code , if you could help me with this one  , I have other similar classes so that I can write tests for all other on my own.  Appreciate your help ! Here is the link --
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700179/xunit-unit-testing-for-dot-net-core-application)

Comment: have you got a chance to look into my other question?. I have also posted the solution , but not sure if that is properly done or not.

Comment: @Narru007 posted an answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for helping me out !